# How do you get a shrine

Tags: dragonvale

I was reading an article about the shrines in dragon vale but I could not figure out how to get them.

Answer (score 1):

You buy the shrine under the 'Buildings' section in shops.

You have to go to shop and navigate to 'Buildings'.